# TSL / SQL PERCENTILE_CONT should return 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct-values, percentile

I am working on a T-SQL query (I'm running a SQL Server database) that should compute the median from a list of values. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER (ORDER BY age) as Age 
FROM 
   peopleDB 
WHERE 
   <expressions>;
```

The database has 100 rows. The query returns the median (the same value) 100 times, but my goal is to only return it once. I've been trying to use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in a variety of ways but it returns syntax error every time. `DISTINCT` is currently not supported by the database.

Is there any chance I am overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of TSL.  But, one of the following might work:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER (ORDER BY age) as Age
FROM peopleDB
WHERE <expressions>
limit 1;

SELECT top 1 PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER (ORDER BY age) as Age
FROM peopleDB
WHERE <expressions>;

SELECT max(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER (ORDER BY age)) as Age
FROM peopleDB
WHERE <expressions>;

select max(age)
from (SELECT top 1 PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER (ORDER BY age) as Age
      FROM peopleDB
      WHERE <expressions>
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an empty over clause.

```
SELECT 
   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY <column>) OVER () as Age 
FROM 
   peopleDB 
WHERE 
   <expressions>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue & reading this helped me realise solution. So the SQL syntax (as I'm not familiar with TSQL) to your problem is:

```
SELECT 
   Distinct PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) within group (ORDER BY age) over () as Age 
FROM 
   peopleDB 
WHERE 
   <expressions>;
```

Worked for me!